# C# naming conventions for objects in methods that modify input

Tags: c#, mapping

What is the accepted naming convention for methods that modify or slightly change a passed parameter object?
In particular, methods like this:

```
class Mapper {
    public PersonDTO MapPerson(tPerson p) {
        var person = new PersonDTO {
            ID = p.ID,
            Name = p.Name,
            Country = Retriever.GetCountryName(p.CountryID)
        };

        return person;
    }
}
```

Since the "person" descriptor applies to both the return object as well as the parameter, I'm not sure what's best practice here.

Comment: What exactly are you modifying, if it is say for example registering a person to some service you could say RegisteredPerson instead of Person?

Comment: The parameter object is of type "tPerson", and the return type is of type "PersonDTO".

Comment: Well in the same way you have Person and PersonDTO I would say you have a PersonAdapter ? (or PersonMapper or PersonTransformer depending on what you prefer)

Comment: You didn't change tPerson, did you? You just return a wrapper.

Comment: Good point, I edited my example!

Comment: I think Saint Gerbil has provided you with a few answers to your question.

Comment: @Xymak1y you need to edit your title and text as well. You are not modifying any input, nor are you modifying the "passed parameter object."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Mapper {

    public PersonDTO MapPerson(tPerson person) 
    {
        return new PersonDTO {
             ID = person.ID,
             Name = person.Name
        };
    }
}
```

problem solved?
your extra variable could be described as [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).
if you need to an additional variable, call it `result` or `retval`. if it is not an return value, call it `personDto`.

and for the method, always describe what you you do. in this case, you map a person, so `MapPerson` seems fine to me.

Comment: I think this sounds ok to me although, I would say PersonMapper rather than MapPerson.

Comment: The name of the class that is.

Comment: @Monkieboy only if it is the only function, yes!

Answer (score 3):

You could write this as a constructor instead:

```
class PersonDTO
{
    public PersonDTO(tPerson person)
    {
        ID = person.ID;
        Name = person.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: it can be painful, to write copy constructors in n-tier environment, to take care of the conversion. A mapper (like automapper) is often a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Call your method

> CompleteAndMapPerson